how to increase the font size of "lable and sample size plot when using ggbarstats in R
enter image description here
now I am struggling to change the font size of (sample size (n=193)) and percentage 74% these kinds of texts in the picture.
Anyone could help me, thanks in advacne
I tried many ways, none of them working

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete example code and a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

You can set the font size for the labels and the sample size using the arguments label.args and sample.size.label.args.
Using the default example from ggstatsplot::ggbarstats:
library(ggstatsplot)

ggbarstats(
  mtcars,
  x = vs, y = cyl,
  label.args = list(size = 6, fill = "white"),
  sample.size.label.args = list(size = 6)
)


